# Bootstrap table not showing borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I wish to add a table dynamically using JQuery when I press a button. I want it to have borders in my table that I create. However I never get the borders showing.
I am using Django templates.

**Base HTML:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'designer/style.css' %}" />
  <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>

  {% block extrahead %} {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Main html that extends base.html:**

```html
{% extends 'designer/base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}Mains Primary{% endblock %} 

{% block extrahead %}
  <script src="{% static 'designer/js/mains_primary_edit.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'designer/style.css' %}" /> 

{% block content %}
  <div class="row" id="primary_tables"></div>
  <button onclick="add_table()">Click me</button> 
{% endblock %}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
// Most of this is from: https://www.codemag.com/article/1601031/CRUD-in-HTML-JavaScript-and-jQuery-Using-the-Web-API

$(document).ready(function() {});

function add_table() {
  let table_html = make_fixed_winding_table()
  $("#primary_tables").append(table_html);
}

function make_fixed_winding_table() {
  var table_html = '<div class="col-3"> \
        <table className="table table-bordered table-primary"> \
            <thead> \
            <tr> \
                <th colSpan="2"><h4>Name:<span className="badge bg-secondary">P1</span></h4></th> \
            </tr> \
            </thead> \
            <tbody> \
            <tr> \
                <td>John</td> \
                <td>Doe</td> \
            </tr> \
            <tr> \
                <td>Mary</td> \
                <td>Moe</td> \
            </tr> \
            </tbody> \
        </table> \
    </div>'

  return table_html
}
```

Any ideas why I can't get a bordered table to work. Is it some interaction between jquey and bootstrap?

Thank you,
John.

I have tried just plain HTML with a fixed bootstrap table, with borders and that worked.
It just seems to be when I try and generate one.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `className` instead of `class` in your javascript `make_fixed_winding_table ` function.

Comment: Why do you have an empty ``$(document).ready(function() {});``?

Comment: first of all it seems you are using a template engine thus those `{% %}` tags (maybe Django?). Secondly you are using the `className` attribute like it was a valid html attribute (that isn't) but it's more likely you got from the React(?) syntax. By the way if you tried to just make a table like that in a classic static html file it was easier to catch the problem. As stated before by the first comment, the className attribute is the culprit of your problem as far as we can say. And I always wonder why people don't use the _inspect element_ feature on browser before asking for help